AWS API connectivity to GovCloud from Internet
I want to be able to use the AWS CLI from anywhere on the Internet (my laptop, GCP VM, etc) to hit the AWS API running on the GovCloud partition.  For example, I want to run (amongst other things) aws sts get-caller-identity against my AWS GovCloud account.
Are there any restrictions on hitting the AWS API from outside of GovCloud from an IP-level?  Is the IP-level access to the API wide-open like it is on the regular AWS partition?

The docs make no mention of any restriction. When I copy this the STS Gov Cloud endpoint into my browser I get redirected to the main AWS website. That suggests they are not restricted https://sts.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com
